# replace a string in a file with ant that is contained in a gzip file

Tags: ant

How do I replace, with ant, a string in a file that is contained in a gzipped file?
Ed

Answer (score 0):

The way you eat an elephant, one bite at at time:

1. Extract the file from gzip.
2. Copy file to new location in the process replacing the string (use filterset for this).
3. Update gzip with the updated file.